# How to make a recursive equatable protocol for swift struct

Tags: swift, equatable

Is there any way that can I set up a protocol such that if we define a struct where all its properties conforms to `Equatable`, then it becomes automatically `Equatable` without having to write all the boilerplate code to compare every properties within the class. Ideally this protocol also inherits from `Equatable`.

for example, if there such a protocol is called `RecursiveEquatable` and I define a struct

```
struct A: RecursiveEquatable {
  let value: Int
}
```

then I don't need to write the boilerplate code

```
public func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
  return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

Comment: You could use `MirrorType` to retrieve all properties and compare them. However, this would not ensure that all properties are `Equatable` during compile time.

Comment: This isn't really possible. Are you aware of any languages that have such a feature? I'm curious as to how it's done.

Comment: Yes, case classes in scala have these feature. @alexander-momchliov